# Identifying Lego kits from unopened bags for library

Tags: set-identification, juniors

I'm a librarian and we recently received one of the Junior Maker Lego kits that LEGO distributed to 15 libraries in each state. It's a wonderful kit and includes a lot of basic blocks along with many numbered bags that clearly go to sets. However, none of the set information is included, nor can I find it online. Some I know are from the Chima theme based on the minifigs. I'm happy to upload pics if you all wouldn't mind helping, but there's about 20 different ones. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Without pictures, there's not really a whole lot to go on.

Comment: I did some research on the program, and there's a lot of material on the ALSC website, include, for example, this toolkit:  http://www.ala.org/alsc/sites/ala.org.alsc/files/content/Juniors%20Librarian%20Toolkit_September_FINAL.pdf

Comment: I suspect that the intention is that the exact sets don't matter, and they may even vary between kits. Because those pieces are going to end up really mixed very quickly, so either you're going to spend a lot of time policing and sorting, or you'll end up with one big pile of pieces. Personally I would resign myself to that now and move on...

Comment: I think @Mσᶎ pretty much has the right idea. creativity gets messy and there's little point in attempting to catalog the exact element mix.

Comment: While I agree that Mσᶎ is probably right, there can be some value in having some instructions that can be made from the supplied kits so that the kids have something they can start from.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to know, I would suggest identifying the most unusual part in a bag, then  using that part, search for what sets it has appeared in recently.  Each piece usually has a small number printed on it.  Use this part number on bricklink, or peeron to search for the part, and then click the link that shows you what sets it has appeared in.

Alternatively, take a picture of the bag and post it to the [AFOLs of Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/AdultFansOfLego/) group and you'll probably have an answer in 5 minutes or less.